# Is there any way to set String property of class depending on tablename?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables in my database, at "retail" schema, with indent column sets:

"vegetable_group":

```
+------------------+--------------------+
| (varchar) id     | (varchar) value    |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 1                | good_vegetables    |
| 2                | bad_vegetables     |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

"fruit_group":

```
+------------------+--------------------+
| (varchar) id     | (varchar) value    |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 3                | good_fruit         |
| 4                | bad_fruit          |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

also i have an enum in database type product_type as enum ('fruit', 'vegetable');

this is my entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "retail", name = "vegetable_group")
@SecondaryTables({
        @SecondaryTable(schema = "retail", name = "fruit_group",
                pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        )
})
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private enum ProductType {
       vegetable, fruit
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    ProductType productType;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

}
```

and simple ProductRepository

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {

}
```

I need to set somehow the value of product.productType depending on the table, from combined data...

Can i somehow simply do that?

**Upd.**

I'm using @SecondaryTable, because i need to get data from two tables using a single entity. For example, i have a Product with id 99. I don't know whether it is a vegetable or a fruit. The common approach for such process is to create two entities: Fruit and Vegetable and search them by id's. But database structure can't be changed so i use one entity Product, that gets data from both tables by unique id.

Comment: I'm not really sure it will work as you want, does `productRepository.findAll()` returns you 4 entities in this case? Probably you missing the point of `@SecondaryTable` annotation, it is supposed to fulfill fields, that are not in the first table, it doesn't split your data among different tables.

Comment: Yes, it returns 4 entities and it satisfies my goal, but i also neet to define the entity property values depending on the table. None of these tables has a field with type...

Comment: Seems to me you have 2 completely different entities you are trying to shoehorn into 1 type by incorrectly using `@SecondaryTable`. You need to make your question about what it is you want to do rather than asking about your (incorrect) solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Yes, entities are different, but i use SecondaryTable, because the data in these two tables is the same (same columns). The last problem is to assign different enums to these entities.
I need to do UNION between these two tables, but jpa doesn't support it, so i use Secondary table, but can't assign different enum types.

Comment: Could anyone help?